# Need to extract value from the string which contains semicolon and colon

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one column that contains the value in the value-key pair. But I need to extract only value from that column.

Input Table:

```
+------+---------------------------------+
| Col1 |              Col2               |
+------+---------------------------------+
|    1 | Val1:Key1;Val2:Key2;;;Val4:Key4 |
+------+---------------------------------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+------+--------------------------------+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 |              Col2              | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |
+------+--------------------------------+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | Val1:Key1;Val2:Key2;;Val4:Key4 | Val1 | Val2 |      | Val4 |
+------+--------------------------------+------+------+------+------+
```

Explanation:

As Col2 contains the value in value-key pair out of which I need to extract only value and store it in a different column and wherever there is no value we need to put it as blank. So basically, need to identify ; and :.

My attempt:

```
SELECT
  Col1,
  SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col1, 'Key1:(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1), 5) AS Col2
From table_name;


DB - Oracle Sql Developer tool
Version - 19c
```

I am not sure whether this is the optimized way to handle this requirement and hence seeking help for the same.

Comment: This is exactly the same problem as your previous question with the key-value pair reversed to value-key. Use the previous solution with match in the regular expression reversed `REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col2, '(;|^)([^;]*?):key1(;|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 2)` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VNt-LF6a)